# Devforce Code First - .ibmmx Not Generating

Tags: devforce

After upgrading to Visual studio 2017 and Devforce 7.5.1, my application is no longer re-generating the .ibmmx file.  Strangely, the .ibmmx re-generates correctly on my home PC but not on my work laptop.  Both have visual studio 2017 and Devforce 7.5.1 installed.  I've checked the DRC Code First troubleshooting article and can confirm that Devforce.cf is correctly added.

I've also tried create a new code first app from scratch and the .ibmmx does not generate.  The build message is as follows:

```
1>DevForceEntityModelMetadataDeploy:
1>  In EntityModelMetadataDeploy.  Parms:  Assembly='C:\Users\idids\source\repos\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe', TargetFolder='C:\Users\idids\source\repos\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2'
1>  IdeaBlade.VisualStudio.Build.Tasks, Version=7.5.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=287b5094865421c0
1>  Trying model metadata discovery for C:\Users\idids\source\repos\WpfApplication2\WpfApplication2\bin\Debug\WpfApplication2.exe
1>  Creating metadata from EntityManager 'TestEntities'
1>  Searching for connectionString named 'TestEntities': found
1>  Model metadata created for TestEntities
```

It seems that the model is generating but the .ibmmx is not being created.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are any errors shown in the Error List or elsewhere in the output window?  It's possible that either the .ibmmx couldn't be written due to file permissions or couldn't be added to the VS project (due to any number of problems).  If you see the .ibmmx in the folder but it hasn't been added to the project in VS then we known it's an issue with VS.  In that case, how many VS solutions do you have open at one time?  Also, which edition of VS2017 are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I can confirm the following: 1) There are no errors / warnings and nothing else in the output windows (except the expected build successes). 2) The .ibmmx file is not being generated i.e. it is not being written to the folder (I've also checked every folder in case of a mapping issue). 3) I'm using Visual Studio 2017 Professional version 15.7.5 (note I was running an earlier version of VS2017 Pro and had the same issue).

Comment: A visual studio file access permission issue seems logical but not sure how to investigate further.  I’ve tried the following without any success: 1) Re-installing Visual studio. 2) Re-installing Devforce (multiple times, before and after visual studio installation.

Comment: I use Visual SVN for source control and I thought that might be the a contributing factor.  I’ve tried without Visual SVN being installed with no success.

Comment: The only difference between my machines is that I'm running Windows 10 Home on my laptop (the machine with the .ibmmx issue) and Windows 10 Pro on my desktop (.ibmmx correctly generates).  My next step is to do a clean build on my laptop with windows 10 Pro.  Before I do this, do you have any guidance for investigating further?  Is there anything I need to enable in Visual Studio to get the .ibmmx to generate in terms of file access restrictions?

Comment: If the ibmmx file isn't created the only causes I can think of are permissions or some error when serializing the model to a file.  In theory, either a permissions or serialization error should be logged somewhere.  Check the Windows Event Viewer logs to see if anything was logged there.  Try creating your solution in a folder which has wide-open file permissions to see if that works.  Also, when you installed DevForce, did the setup program run and ask you for your license key?

Comment: Yes. The setup asked for a license key. I’ve checked the event viewer and can’t see anything suspicious. Interestingly, I've installed VS2015 Pro and the .ibmmx generates correctly so it must be something to do with the VS2017 installation. I’m going to do a refresh install with windows 10 pro and VS2017.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm having the same issue, even if i delete the ibmmx is does not regenerate i followed the steps provided here with no luck:

http://drc.ideablade.com/devforce-2012/bin/view/Documentation/code-first-troubleshooting